# AWS EC2 Describe Instances - Filtering by Root device

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

Hoping you can help with this query. Hopefully the answer should allow me to construct better queries down the line.
I am trying to filter by the root device of a particular instance and get the root devices volume id. Could you explain how I could join two such queries. Searching for DeviceName /dev/sda1 and to then get the corresponding VolumeId.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id i-02bc19e18ef09cdbe --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].BlockDeviceMappings[]'

[
    {
        "Ebs": {
            "AttachTime": "2017-04-20T13:32:04.000Z",
            "VolumeId": "vol-0118bd9c0a08164f2",
            "DeleteOnTermination": false,
            "Status": "attached"
        },
        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1"
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried `jq`?

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirement, or show some sample output? Do you want the `VolumeId` for `/dev/sda1` of multiple instances?

Comment: I would like the VolumeId for /dev/sda1, I am currently specifying a single instance I would assume however the filter/query is written could be applied to more than one instance. I have not tried jq, is this something that would be required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a little old, but here's a possible solution for you. Making one assumption - namely, that the root device is `/dev/sda1`. Which I think is a fairly good assumption for AWS. If you don't specify an instance-id, all of the instances will be returned. Then I'm doing a search of DeviceName equal to /dev/sda1. After the search term, a list is created with DeviceName and VolumeId.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].BlockDeviceMappings[?DeviceName == '/dev/sda1'].{DeviceName: DeviceName, VolumeID: Ebs.VolumeId}
```

Comment: What if we don't want to assume /dev/sda1 and take the volume details from RootDeviceName?
How will we construct the query?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but still if anybody needs it, Here is the aws cli command which can be used to retrieve the root volume device name attached to an instance.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids <instance-id> --region <region-name> --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].RootDeviceName" --output text
```

Using output of above command as the input to below command, we can retrieve the volume id..

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes  --region <region name> --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=<instance-id> Name=attachment.device,Values=<output from above command> --query 'Volumes[*].VolumeId' --output text
```